# How do you change the dimension of your input pictures in pytorch?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, python-imaging-library, conv-neural-network, pytorch

i made a convolutional nuralnetwork and i want it to take input pictures and output pictures but when i turn the pictures into tensors they have the wrong dimension :

```
RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [20, 3, 5, 5], but got 3-dimensional input of size [900, 1440, 3] instead
```

how do i change the dimension of the pictures ? and why does it need to be changed?
and how do i make the output an picture?
i tryed to use

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
[transforms.ToTensor(),
 transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

to normilize the img but it didnt change the dimension .
here is my nuralnet

```
    def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    torch.nn.Module.dump_patches = True
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 20, 5)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20, 16, 5)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 16*5*5)


def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
    x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 )
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)


    return x
```

here i get the image and put it into a list:

```
for i in range(4):
l.append(ImageGrab.grab())
```

and here is the code that turns the img into an tensor

```
k=torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(l[1],dtype="int32" ))
```

Comment: `torch.nn` only supports mini-batches. The input should be in the form (batch_size, channels, height, width). You seem to be missing the batch dimension. Add `.unsqueeze(0)` to add a fake batch dimension.

Comment: i changed that and now i got the error     `RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [20, 3, 5, 5], expected input[1, 900, 1440, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 900 channels instead`

Comment: i fixed it by transforming before unsqueezing but now i got the error    ` x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 *5)
RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 400]' is invalid for input of size 1268064`
which i guess is an error in the convelution so thank you for helping me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*In summary, according to the comments you and I posted:*

The error is due to `torch.nn` only supports mini-batches. The input should be in the form `(batch_size, channels, height, width)`. You seem to be missing the batch dimension. You can add `.unsqueeze(0)` to add a fake batch dimension in the first position.

In addition to the above, you'll also have to rearrange the dimensions of your image from `[HxWxC]` to `[CxHxW]`. This is done by `.ToTensor()` transformation in PyTorch.

For the size mismatch problem of your input image, you could use transformation like this:

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
                   [transforms.Resize((32,32)),
                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

Comment: thanks it works but now i want the output in the nn to be a picture too how would i have to change the nn to accomplish that?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Do you want to show label predicted by model along-side the picture. You can check the `imshow` function from this official tutorial for this: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#visualize-a-few-images

Comment: i dont want it to predict a label but i want it to predict a picture i want the output to be like the input so i transform the input back into the image but  i dont know how to do that.

Comment: A neural network can output a label only unless you use some advance networks for image generation like GAN (generative models). As far as I could understand from your problem, neural network will give you probabilities of different classes, then you can find the class having the highest probability. Now, instead of showing the class itself, you can plot any image corresponding to that label.